# post user and password from website in Flutter

Tags: html, authentication, flutter, dart

I want to use information from a website in an app I programm in flutter. I need to log in at the website first. The html code of the website is this:

```
<div>Geben Sie Ihren Benutzernamen und Ihr Passwort ein, um sich an der Website anzumelden:</div>
<!-- ###LOGIN_FORM### -->
<form action="/fuer-studierende/intranet/" target="_top" method="post" onsubmit="; return true;">
    <fieldset>
    <legend>Anmelden</legend>
    <div>
        <label for="user">Benutzername:</label>
        <input type="text" id="user" name="user" value="" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="pass">Passwort:</label>
        <input type="password" id="pass" name="pass" value="" data-rsa-encryption="" />
    </div>
```

I need to fill in the user name in line 8 after "value" and the password in line 12 after "value". How can I do this in flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fill in those fields in a browser and hit `submit` the browser sends a request to the `action` url, using the `method` specified in the `form` tag. If the method is `POST` it collects the fields, encodes them using a format called `x-www-form-urlencoded` and adds that as the body of the request.

(Note that the browser may take some additional steps like running JavaScript, which may alter the values. You would need to alter your values in the same way.)

The Dart `package:http` provides all these functions for you. If you provide a `Map<String, String>` as the body parameter of a `post`, it encodes them for you and sets the content type.

```
void send() async {
  var form = <String, String>{
    'user': 'miwa',
    'pass': 'M1VVA%',
  };

  var res = await http.post(
    'https://some.website.de/fuer-studierende/intranet/',
    body: form,
  );
  print(res.statusCode);
  print(res.body);
}
```

Of course, you will likely receive in response a large lump of HTML and a session cookie, which you will have to parse and extract respectively.

Comment: It works thanks. But in my example I have a problem with the function "print(res.body"). Only a few lines of the html code are shown. Does this happen, because something doesn´t work or does the type var isnt´t big enough?

Comment: That's just the console truncating at ~1000 characters. Use `print(res.body.length);` to confirm that the whole response is actually there.

Comment: Another problem is, that there is a button on the Website to Login. How can I click the button with flutter after filling in the username and password?
I added the code, which you send, but I get a response with the code from the same Website without a values I filled in.

Comment: The code above mimics what the browser would probably do when you click the login button. Of course, there maybe be other hidden fields in the html you need to post, or the server may have expected a cookie to be returned, or there may be JavaScript hidden behind the button too. You need to dig deeper into the HTML of the login page and/or speak with the server admin to see what you are missing.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use flutters WebView package to send data from Flutter to HTML using JavaScript.

Follow this short tutorial to get a quick overview off the WebView package:
https://medium.com/flutter/the-power-of-webviews-in-flutter-a56234b57df2

If you assign a WebViewController to the WebView (see tutorial) you can use the controller to send JavaScript messages to the HTML webpage from Flutter.

Use the following code in the «onPageFinished» function of the WebView widget:

```
_webController.evaluateJavascript(
   '''
     var email = document.getElementById("user");
     var password = document.getElementById("pass");
     email.value = "${_yourFlutterUserTextController.text}";
     password.value = "${_yourFlutterPasswordTextController.text}"
   '''
);
```

As you can see you can place Flutter variables like the username and password from your Flutter app and send the JavaScript snippet to the website which executes the JavaScript.

You could also fire a button click after filling out the login...

Hope this helps and good luck!